# how open by vs a dump file that create by task manager and see the source code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I have c++ source code that I compile it by vs 2008.
when I run the program by F5 and break the runnig. I can save it as dump file and I can open it by clicking on the file by visual studio and I can see c++ source code in step that I save it.

but when I use taskmanger and create  dump file from program's perocess
when I open it I see only assembely code and not c++ code?
how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinDbg.exe to open those dump files. It is available for free from Microsoft as part of the Microsoft Debugging Tools For Windows at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx. You can set it to grab your source files so you can see your source along with the dump information. For information on how to use WinDbg, check out http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=VS.85).aspx